# jquery data() method does not work in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have the following link:

```
<a href="/Packages/PackageActionDownloadAsync" data-ajax-type="Download" data-ajax-packageid="AGI-VS-GAME-M52-1.5.3.2.67" data-ajax-machineid="30" class="iconGear action tip" data-hasqtip="true" oldtitle="Download" title="" aria-describedby="qtip-1">Download</a>
```

and javascript code:

```
       var obj = $(this),
            objData = obj.data(),
            packageId = objData.ajaxPackageid,
            operation = objData.ajaxType;
```

I tried this:

```
alert(objData.ajaxPackageid);
alert(objData.ajaxPackageId);
alert(objData.AjaxPackageId);
```

they all return "undefined". The only one that works is this:

```
alert(objData.ajaxType);
```

what is going on?
I'm using **"jquery-1.7.1.js"**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm suprised **any** of them work accessing them like that. You need to access them via string names in jQuery. Like so:

```
var obj = $(this);
alert(obj.data("ajax-packageid"));
alert(obj.data("ajax-type"));
alert(obj.data("ajax-machineid"));
```

Take a look at the **jquery [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) object**

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/xFmn3/

Comment: @ShaneKm For a cross browser solution, you should really use the `.data("")` method.

Comment: It seems they worked due to a quirk of the way `$.fn.data` is implemented in jQuery. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7262427/1852838). I was also surprised to learn you can access them this way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the key for the data you want to receive to the `data()` function.

```
   var obj = $(this),
   packageId = obj.data("ajax-packageid"),
   operation = obj.data("ajax-type");
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/sUSCe/